# Efficient manipulations of binary matrix in numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

By binary matrix, I mean every element in the matrix is either 0 or 1, and I use the `Matrix` class in numpy for this.

First of all, is there a specific type of matrix in numpy for it, or do we simply use a matrix that is populated with 0s and 1s?

Second, what is the *quickest* way for creating a **square matrix full of 0s** given its dimension with the `Matrix` class? Note: `numpy.zeros((dim, dim))` is not what I want, as it creates a 2-D array with float `0.`

Third, I want to get and set any given row of the matrix frequently. For get, I can think of using `row = my_matrix.A[row_index].tolist()`, which will return a list representation of the given row. For set, it seems that I can just do `my_matrix[row_index] = row_list`, with `row_list` being a list of the same length as the given row. Again, I wonder whether they are the most efficient methods for doing the jobs.

Comment: Why do you need `numpy.matrix` instead of `numpy.ndarray`?  Why to you convert rows to a list when retrieving them?

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I need a matrix because it has ready-made functions for matrix-specific calculations. I convert a row into a list upon retrieval because I need to serialize it into JSON.

Comment: Many of these matrix-specific operation can also be applied to arrays – that's why I'm asked.  And if you need to serialise things to JSON, chances are you bottleneck is elsewhere, and you don't need to care about the speed of retrieving a line from the matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a numpy array whose elements can be either 0 or 1, use the `dtype = 'bool'` parameter:

```
arr = np.zeros((dim,dim), dtype = 'bool')
```

Or, to convert `arr` to a numpy matrix:

```
arr = np.matrix(arr)
```

To access a row:

```
arr[row_num]
```

and to set a row:

```
arr[row_num] = new_row
```

is the quickest way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'd prefer to have the elements in the matrix to be `0` or `1`, not `Ture` nor `False`. In addition, `arr[row_num]` will return a 1-D matrix object, not an array or list.

Comment: `True` and `False` are basically the same as `0` and `1` – just try these expresions in the interactive interpreter: `0 == False`, `3 * True`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach They are the same, but `True` and `False` occupy 8 bits, as do `0` and `1` (in Python). It'd be nice to have numpy arrays whose entries are actual bits...

Comment: @étale-cohomology `arr = np.zeros((dim,dim), dtype=int)`